# After upgrade from Clarion 9 to Clarion 10 an error acquiring

Tags: clarion

After upgrade app from  Clarion 9.1 to Clarion 10 and after first build an error acquiring.

**Error:** Unresolved `External SHGetFolderPathA` in `EFOCUS.obj`. I include `efocus.clw` in solution. `Efocus.clw` and `efocus.inc` are in **C10** folder.

Help me please

Comment: are the files in the root directory of `C10` ? if so, try moving them to `C10\LibSrc\win`

Answer (score 0):

I dont use the enhanced focus feature, but a couple of things might help:

SHGetFolderPathA is deprecated but should still be around since its in Shell32.dll. Its possible SV eliminated it from their lib in lieu of the replacement call (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181(v=vs.85).aspx ), but I doubt it. Even so, you could make your own lib using the DLL and Libmaker.exe (which is shipped in \c10\bin).

It may be simpler than this. Delete the clw and obj from your app folder (or sub-folder where the .RED directs them) and recompile.